# Function defined inside of an object doesn't return the value?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to return the name of the element inside of the object. Second element is function `getBook()` that should return the name of the book but I'm getting `undefined` in my console. I have defined the second variable get name that is referencing to the function inside of the object. I'm not sure if I can use return this.element. If anyone can explain why my code is failing I would appreciate that. Thank you.

```
var books = { 
    name: 'Goodnight Moon', 
    getBook() { 
        return this.name; 
    } 
}; 

var getName = books.getBook; 
console.log(getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) books to the getName function expression. Otherwise the context of `this` will refer to the `window` object:

```js
var books = {
  name: 'Goodnight Moon',
  getBook() {
    return this.name;
  }
};

var getName = books.getBook.bind(books);
console.log(getName());
```

Comment: Carl, thanks for taking time to respond. Please would you explain why we have to use bind and why my original code for returning undefined?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if it needs further explanation.

Comment: @espresso_coffee: Think of `this` as another function parameter. It gets set by the caller to some value depending on how the function was invoked. You can also set it manually when invoking like `getName.call(books)`, or as shown above, you can create a new function using `.bind()` that has a value permanently bound as the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could simply do

```js
// same object definition
var books = { 
    name: 'Goodnight Moon', 
    getBook() { 
        return this.name; 
    } 
};

// but call:
books.getBook();
console.log(books.getBook());
```